# Find Closest Match (Conditional Lookup)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, search-indexing

I am trying to do conditional lookup in Excel (MacOS). Let's say I have the table shown below, and I want to search for (type=alpha, length=165). In the table, there isn't an exact match so I'm trying to do approximate search for a row which satisfies the following conditions:

1. The entry's type must match. In this case, the entry must have type alpha.
2. The entry's length must be within 20 units of the actual length. In this case, the actual length is 165, so the entry's length must be between 145 and 185.
3. If multiple entries satisfy the conditions, return the entry with the closest length. In this case, both rows 1 and 2 match the criteria but row 2's length is closest to 165, so pick row 2.

If it finds such an entry, I want the code to return the entry's id. So if I look up (type=alpha, length=165), the program should return al2.

I have tried using index and match. But since I have one equality condition and one inequality condition, I was unable to get it to work. Is there a way to solve this using excel functions or will I need to use VBA?

|  | A (type) | B (length) | C (id) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alpha | 150 | al1 |
| 2 | alpha | 170 | al2 |
| 3 | alpha | 190 | al3 |
| 4 | alpha | 30 | al4 |
| 5 | beta | 200 | be1 |
| 6 | beta | 40 | be2 |
| 7 | beta | 30 | be3 |
| 8 | gamma | 150 | ga1 |
| 9 | gamma | 450 | ga2 |

Comment: Don't have Excel accessible to me at the moment, but can't you use `IFS()` so that the conditions evaluated are 1) entry matches Column A, 2) `SMALL(ABS([Column B]-[Entry])<=20))`?  May need to be corrected, I'm typing this from a phone, but something along those lines?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How should I implement the condition 1) that the entry matches column A? Also, I'm not very familiar with IFS but doesn't it return the value associated with the first true condition. Would nested-if work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is tagged with a relatively old version of Excel, so the solution below uses helper columns in the solution.

[image]

Values in column Fit_Criteria are TRUE if the Type and Length values meet the criteria of being the specified input type and within 20 of the specified input length, FALSE otherwise.

Values in column Length2 take the value 21 if Fit_Criteria is FALSE. Otherwise, the value is set as the absolute difference between the Length and the specified input length. Finding the row with the minimum value of Length2 (almost) solves the problem.

Values in closest are TRUE if both the value in Length2 is equal to the minimum of this column **and** Fit_Criteria is TRUE.

The solution is the first row in which closest is TRUE. There is no solution if all entries in column Closest are FALSE.

**Can this be solved without the helper columns**

The helper column Fit_Criteria is dependent on the input Type value (in cell `I3`. Further the other two helper columns are both dependent on Fit_Criteria, so changing the input Type value will, potentially change the values in all 3 helper columns. This presents a problem if multiple sets of inputs need to be matched and so it is legitimate to consider whether it is possible to solve the problem without resorting to helper columns.

For the latest version of Excel (Office 365) the answer is a clear "Yes". The solution is shown below, where columns `E` and `F` represent three different sets of inputs with the corresponding outputs in column `G`.

[image: Screenshot without helpers]

In an expanded format, the formula in cell `G2` is

```
=LET(
     criteria,(ABS(B$2:B$10-F2)<=20)*(A$2:A$10=E2),
     length2,IF(NOT(criteria),21,ABS(B$2:B$10-F2)),
     closest,(length2=MIN(length2))*criteria,
     INDEX(C$2:C$10,MATCH(1,closest,0))
    )
```

and this formula simply uses the very powerful `LET` function to effectively define variables called `criteria`, `length2` and `closest` which serve the
same purpose as the helper columns.

For ease of explanation, unlike in the earlier solution, I have not trapped the "no match" condition, but wrapping an `IFERROR` function around the final `INDEX` argument easily adds this.

The `LET` function is not available in Excel 2016, so can helper columns be avoided without the use of `LET`?

The answer to this is probably "Yes". Probably because the suggested formula below uses an array function (entered by use of the control, shift and enter keys from the formula bar) which are permissible in Excel 2016, but I don't have a version available in which to test the formula.

Again, in expanded format, the formula for cell `G2` can be re-written as

```
=IFERROR(
         INDEX(
               C$2:C$10,
               MATCH(
                     1,
                     (
                      (
                       (
                        (A$2:A$10=E2)*
                        (ABS(B$2:B$10-F2)<=20)
                       )*
                       ABS(B$2:B$10-F2)
                      )+
                      (1-
                         (
                          (A$2:A$10=E2)*
                          (ABS(B$2:B$10-F2)<=20)
                         )
                      )*
                      21=
                      MIN(
                          (
                           (
                            (A$2:A$10=E2)*
                            (ABS(B$2:B$10-F2)<=20)
                           )*
                           ABS(B$2:B$10-F2)
                          )+
                          (1-
                             (
                              (A$2:A$10=E2)*
                              (ABS(B$2:B$10-F2)<=20))
                          )*
                          21
                         )
                    )*
                    (A$2:A$10=E2)*
                    (ABS(B$2:B$10-F2)<=20),
                     0
                    )
              ),
         "No Match"
        )
```

Note that the phrase `(A$2:A$10=E2)*(ABS(B$2:B$10-F2)<=20)` occurs five times in this formula. This is effectively the `criteria` array used in the previous `LET` function.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I accidentally tagged excel 2010, I have excel 2016 (sorry). Since I have a bunch of values to look up, would it be possible to do this without helper columns?

Comment: It is possible. I have edited my answer to add two possible solutions which do not rely on helper columns.

Comment: Thank you so much!